# Redirect to web folder

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to configure redirects on a Drupal site using Apache web server. I'm trying to implement what described in [Remove /web part from a Composer based Drupal site](https://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/remove-web-part-composer-based-drupal-site), but I cannot get it to work. I have several Drupal sites running in /var/www/html/drupal. The configuration in the httpd.conf file is created with the following.

```yaml
- name: create drupal httpd conf
    copy:
      content: |
               <VirtualHost *:80>
                 ServerName qsd
                 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal
                 <Directory />
                    Options FollowSymlinks
                    AllowOverride All
                 </Directory>
               </VirtualHost>
      dest: /etc/httpd/conf.d/drupal.conf
```

```yaml
- name: allow override /var/www/html
    copy:
      content: |
                <Directory "/var/www/html">
                  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                  AllowOverride All
                  Require all granted
                </Directory>
      dest: /etc/httpd/conf.d/app.conf
```

I've added the following lines to the settings.php file.

```php
if ( isset($GLOBALS['request']) && '/web/index.php' === $GLOBALS['request']->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME') ) {
    $GLOBALS['request']->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/index.php');
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the .htaccess file correct for the Drupal site which is in /var/www/html/drupal/app. In /var/www/html/drupal/app/.htaccess, I have the following lines.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Redirect to the sub-directory because that's where Drupal is installed.
  RewriteBase /app
  RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In var/www/html/drupal/app/web/.htaccess I have the following lines.

```
RewriteBase /web
```

When I visit https://example.com/app, I get redirected to my OIDC provider but redirect_uri is missing the /app part. When I visit https://example.com/app/user/login I get a 404, but before adding the .htaccess file, https://example.com/app/web/user/login was working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the `RewriteBase /web` meant to achieve in the `/app/web/.htaccess` file?

Comment: Check if this my answer helps you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536992/drupal-redirect-to-web-folder/71363570#71363570